# how to hide ul li with specific class on page load by default before toggle click function apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, treeview

I have toggle tree which responds on click i.e. show or hide UL>li. I want to hide all the UL --> li who has parent ul-li. To make it more obvious I have apply css background-color to red which I want to be hidden by when page loads but show when it click back.

https://jsfiddle.net/toxic_kz/vr84pd6u/

```
<div>
    <ul class="treeview">
        <li><a>System Administration</a></li>
        <li>
            <a>System Core</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>f2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a>f3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>f4</a></li>
                        <li><a>f5</a></li>
                        <li><a>f6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>f7</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a>f8</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a>f10</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a>f11</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a>f9</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>MyFunctionA</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>f12</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>f13</a></li>
                        <li><a>f14</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>f16</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Course Management</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

### jQuery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.treeview li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('parent');
            }
        });

        // $('.treeview li.parent>ul li').css('display', 'none');
        $('.treeview li.parent>ul li').css('background-color', 'red');

        $('.treeview li.parent > a').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
            $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this is what you want:

```
$(".treeview").find('ul').hide()
```

Place this in your $(document).ready function and it'll hide the underlying unordered list upon page load.